# Tell yum where a local shared library dependency is

Tags: yum, rpmbuild

We are installing a custom rpm which we built using `rpmbuild`. During the install it fails with a dependency on specific file, in our case specifically `libnvidia-ml.so.1`:

```
 Requires: libnvidia-ml.so.1()(64bit)
```

This is installed at `/usr/lib64` but not through the package manager, which cannot change. Is there a way to tell `yum` where to find this file?

I found nothing obvious in the manual, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell yum where to find this file?

`yum/dnf` consults exclusively with your RPM database - there's no way to tell it to take external files into consideration.

Either package this library as an RPM and install it or install whatever you need to install using `rpm --nodeps [packages]`

Comment: Thanks, not what I was hoping, but now I'll move on.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Your best option would be to provide the `.so`-File by your custom-build package itself or add another custom-package which provides the shared library.

---

**The following does not work, as available libraries seem to be stored in rpmdb too**

In this particular case the dependency is not a file, it's a shared library. It should be possible to manually add the library.

1. Ensure the path where you added your library is configured for `ldconfig`

   ```bsh
   grep -R /usr/lib64 /etc/ld.so.*
   ```

   if not, choose a path which is configured, or add the path to the config.
2. Run `ldconfig` to recreate the links and cache

   ```bsh
   ldconfig -v
   ```

   you should see your shared library in the output.

Finally you should be able to install the package.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. Could be that the check done on `yum` without consulting `ld`.

Answer (score 0):

Editing and rebuilding the RPM file that I was attempting to install worked for me. I know the outdated dependency that is unavailable from DNF is on my machine, available, and will remain there. No need to take the time for DNF to understand that too by creating a fake (or real) RPM telling it about all about those things.

I followed:

Allow for new library files to be picked up by `ldconfig` from `/usr/local`.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "/usr/local/lib64\n/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf'
```

Build and install the old library from its source code to `/usr/local` instead of `/usr` to distinguish it from system packages. This will vary by program, but here is an example:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Verify the shared library file is found (in my case it was libtcl and libtk).

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i "libnvidia"
```

Re-build the desired-to-be-installed RPM by re-configuring the specifications file to not require the dependencies that are unknown to DNF (meaning comment out). You may first need to install `rpmrebuild`.

```
rpmrebuild --edit-spec --package original_x86_64.rpm
```

For me it was commenting out lines like:

> ```
> #Requires:      libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)
>
> #Requires:      tcl-devel
> ```

When the rebuild completes it will tell you where the newly built RPM is put. For me it was inside `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64`. Move that wherever you want it then install it. Example:

```
mv ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/original-1.x86_64.rpm rebuilt_x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf install rebuilt_x86_64.rpm
```

---

Source for discovering the existence of `rpmrebuild` and its power to on-the-fly edit an RPM spec file: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/users@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/V2ZJORVHTA34UOJVRA2SEVNTJCM4ETXM/